# How to switch jQuery document ready into element in viewport?

Tags: jquery, animation, element, viewport

I wanted to implement a CSS/jQuery animated bars into my website, however I don't want it to just load whenever the website is re-loaded. I want it to be animated when going in and out of the viewport. I know that I still need to do an animation to unload, but I want to make the load animation be triggered first.

I tried the below, but it's not responding for some reason. When the skillbar jquery function is inserted in window.scroll after checkanimation function it works on EVERY scroll, but when moved directly to checkanimation function and assigned to respond when parent div "kompetencje" is in viewport it's not responding.

Any suggestions? Thank You.

https://jsfiddle.net/mmsmsy/7zymr7zq/2/

```
function isElementInViewport(elem) {
var $elem = $(elem);

// Get the scroll position of the page.
var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

// Get the position of the element on the page.
var elemTop = Math.round( $elem.offset().top );
var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
}

// Check if it's time to start the animation.
function checkAnimation() {
var $elem = $('#kompetencje');

if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
    // Start the animation
    jQuery('.skillbar').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
            width:jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
        },1000);
    });
}
}
```

Comment: you've defined a function twice with the same name, the second time replaces the content of the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `checkAnimation()` function was defined twice but with different actions, so this snippet moves the content of the second function into the first and omits the second definition.

```js
function isElementInViewport(elem) {
  var $elem = $(elem);

  // Get the scroll position of the page.
  var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
  var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

  // Get the position of the element on the page.
  var elemTop = Math.round($elem.offset().top);
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

  return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
}

// Check if it's time to start the animation.
function checkAnimation() {

  // Affixing handler
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $(".junior").offset().top;
  var x = $(window).height();
  if (window_top > div_top) {
    $("ul.menusy").addClass("affixed");
  } else if (window_top < (div_top + x)) {
    $("ul.menusy").removeClass("affixed");
  }

  var $elem = $('#kompetencje');
  if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
    // Start the animation
    jQuery('.skillbar').each(function() {
      jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
        width: jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
      }, 1000);
    });
  } else {
    jQuery('.skillbar-bar').stop(true,false).width(0);
  }
}

// Capture scroll events
$(window).scroll(function() {
  checkAnimation();

});

$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(e) {
  // target element id
  var id = $(this).attr('href');

  // target element
  var $id = $(id);
  if ($id.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  // prevent standard hash navigation (avoid blinking in IE)
  e.preventDefault();

  // top position relative to the document
  var pos = $id.offset().top - 100;

  // animated top scrolling
  $('body, html').animate({
    scrollTop: pos
  }, 200);

});


// Unified scroll listener
/*
$(function() {
   $(window).scroll(checkAnimation);
   checkAnimation();
});
*/
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */
    [class*="col-"] {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Specify Font";
    src: url(fonts/specify/SpecifyPERSONAL-ExExpMedium.ttf);}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Theano Font";
    src: url(fonts/theano/TheanoOldStyle-Regular.ttf);}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Kayak Font";
    src: url(fonts/kayak/KayakSansRegular.otf);}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Kayak Font";
    src: url(fonts/kayak/KayakSansBold.otf);
    font-weight: bold;}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Adam Font";
    src: url(fonts/adam/ADAMCGPRO.otf);}
html,
body {
 background: #edefee; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #edefee, #eaeceb); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #edefee, #eaeceb); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #edefee, #eaeceb); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
 background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #edefee, #eaeceb); /* Standard syntax */
 color: rgb(25,25,25);
 font-family: "Kayak Font";
 font-size: 18px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;}
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all .15s;
 transition: all .15s;}
a:hover {
 color: rgb(200,200,200);}
#naglowek {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 200px;
 background: #596476;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0;
 border-left: 2px solid #596476;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(25,25,25);
 margin: 0;
 margin-bottom: 50px;}
h1 {
 width: 850px;
 min-width: 850px;
 color: #fbfbfd;
 font-family: "Adam Font";
 font-size: 50px;
 line-height: 54px;
 text-align: center;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fbfbfd;
 margin: 48px auto 12px auto;}
h2 {
 width: 780px;
 min-width: 780px;
 color: #fbfbfd;
 font-family: "Kayak Font";
 font-size: 24px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto 24px auto;}
ul.menusy {
 display: block;
 width: 750px;
 min-width: 750px;
 height: 32px;
 background: #596476;
 font-family: "Kayak Font";
 font-size: 24px;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0;
 padding-top: 1px;
 margin: 0 auto;}
ul.menusy.affixed {
    z-index: 10000;
    margin-left: -375px;
    position: fixed; top: 0; left: 50%;}
#naglowek li{
 display: inline;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;}
#naglowek li a {
 background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent 50%, #677689 51%, #677689 100%);
    background-size: 200%;
    color: #fbfbfd;
 padding: 6px 15px;
 -webkit-transition: all .2s;
 transition: all .2s;}
#naglowek li a:hover {
 background-position: 0 100%;}
#glowneMenu {
 display: block;
 font-family: "Kayak Font";
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0;
 border-left: 2px solid #596476;
 margin: 0;}
#glowneMenu img {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto 3vw auto;}
.zdjecie {
 display: block;
 width: 50%;
 min-width: 235px;
 padding: 0;
 border-radius: 100%;}
#kontakt {
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;}
#kontakt p {
 font-size: 24px;
 text-align: center;}
#kontakt i {
 color: #596476;
 font-size: 54px;
 margin: 3vh 0 0 0;}
.kontakt {
 font-size: 32px;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 0 120px 0 120px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(25,25,25);
 margin: 0;}
#tresc {
 color: rgb(25,25,25);
 display: block;
 float: right;
 font-size: 24px;
 text-align: justify;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0 4vw;
 border-left: 2px solid #596476;
 margin: 0;
 margin-bottom: 50px;}
#tresc h1 {
 width: auto;
 color: rgb(25,25,25);
 font-size: 28px;
 line-height: 32px;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 0;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 margin: 0;
 margin-bottom: 24px;}
#zacznijtu {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 90vh;}
.zacznijtu {
 padding: 0 8vw;}
#wyksztalcenie {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 90vh;
 margin: 0;}
ul.punktowanie {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0 8vw;}
summary {
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
 outline: none;}
@keyframes fadeInDown {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-1em);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
details[open] > p {
    animation-name: fadeInDown;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;}
#kompetencje {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 90vh;
 margin: 0;}
table {
 width: 100%;}
.skillbar {
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 margin-bottom:15px;
 width:100%;
 background:gainsboro;
 height:35px;
 border-radius:3px;
 -moz-border-radius:3px;
 -webkit-border-radius:3px;
 -webkit-transition:0.4s linear;
 -moz-transition:0.4s linear;
 -ms-transition:0.4s linear;
 -o-transition:0.4s linear;
 transition:0.4s linear;
 -webkit-transition-property:width, background-color;
 -moz-transition-property:width, background-color;
 -ms-transition-property:width, background-color;
 -o-transition-property:width, background-color;
 transition-property:width, background-color;
}

.skillbar-title {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
width:110px;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:13px;
 color:#ffffff;
 background:#6adcfa;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius:3px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft:3px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:3px;
 border-top-left-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
}

.skillbar-title span {
 display:block;
 background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 padding:0 20px;
 height:35px;
 line-height:35px;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius:3px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft:3px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:3px;
 border-top-left-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
}

.skillbar-bar {
 height:35px;
 width:0px;
 background:#6adcfa;
 border-radius:3px;
 -moz-border-radius:3px;
 -webkit-border-radius:3px;
}

.skill-bar-percent {
 position:absolute;
 right:10px;
 top:0;
 font-size:11px;
 height:35px;
 line-height:35px;
 color:#ffffff;
 color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#doswiadczenie {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 40vh;
 margin: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
 <div id="naglowek">
  <h1>MATEUSZ SEBASTIAN MYSIAK</h1>
  <h2 class="junior">Junior Front-End Developer</h2>
  <ul class="menusy">
   <li><a href="#naglowek">Zacznij tu</a></li>
   <li><a href="#wyksztalcenie">Wykształcenie</a></li>
   <li><a href="#kompetencje">Kompetencje</a></li>
   <li><a href="#doswiadczenie">Doświadczenie</a></li>
   <li><a href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div id="tresc" class="col-xs-9">
    <div id="zacznijtu">
     <h1>O MNIE</h1>
     <p class="zacznijtu">
      Mam na imię Mateusz i zajmuję się Web Development od 2010 roku, kiedy stworzyłem swoją pierwszą, prowizoryczną stronę. Z zawodu jestem inżynierem sieci i systemów komputerowych w małych i średnich firmach, ale ze względu na to jak fascynuje mnie programowanie i jego nieskończone możliwości, zmieniam profesję. Od czasów moich pierwszych kroków wykonałem niezliczone ilości własnych stron i zleceń klientów. Szukam pracy w zespole, dzięki któremu mógłbym dużo szybciej się rozwinąć.
     </p>
    </div>
    <div id="wyksztalcenie">
     <h1>WYKSZTAŁCENIE</h1>
     <p class="wyksztalcenie">
      <ul class="punktowanie">
       <li>
        <details>
          <summary>II Liceum Ogólnokształcące im. Piotra Firleja w Lubartowie (2007-2010)</summary>
          <p>Profil: <strong>matematyczno-fizyczno-informatyczny</strong>,</p>
          <p>przedmiotów rozszerzone: matematyka, fizyka, informatyka, j. angielski.</p>
        </details>
       </li>
       <li>
        <details>
          <summary>Matura (2010)</summary>
          <p>matematyka - 96%,</p>
          <p>fizyka rozszerzona - 50%,</p>
          <p>j. polski - 40%,</p>
          <p>j. angielski - 100%,</p>
          <p>j. angielski rozszerzony - 90%.</p>
        </details>
       </li>
       <li>
        <details>
          <summary>Wojskowa Akademia Techniczna w Warszawie (2010-2011)</summary>
          <p>Kierunek: <strong>Informatyka</strong>.</p>
          <p>Nie ukończyłem ze względu na prace związane z opracowaniem obudowy <a href="#enclosuresMobile">Enclosures Mobile Future</a>.</p>
        </details>
       </li>
       <li>
        <details>
          <summary>Uniwersytet Marii-Curie Skłodowskiej w Lublinie (2011-2013)</summary>
          <p>Kierunek: <strong>Filozofia</strong>.</p>
          <p>Nie ukończyłem ze względu na otwarcie firmy <a href="#enclosuresMobile">Enclosures Mobile</a>.</p>
        </details>
       </li>
       <li>
        <details>
          <summary>Cambridge Certificate of Proficiency in English, CPE (2014)</summary>
        </details>
       </li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
      </ul>
     </p>
    </div>
    <div id="kompetencje">
     <h1>KOMPETENCJE</h1>
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td><strong>Techniczne</strong></td><td><strong>Ogólne</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="75%">
         <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: gray;"><span>HTML5</span></div>
         <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #999;"></div>
         <div class="skill-bar-percent">80%</div>
        </div> <!-- Koniec Paska Umiejetności -->
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="75%">
         <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: gray;"><span>CSS3</span></div>
         <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #999;"></div>
         <div class="skill-bar-percent">80%</div>
        </div> <!-- Koniec Paska Umiejetności -->
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
    <div id="doswiadczenie">
     <h1>DOŚWIADCZENIE</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="glowneMenu" class="col-xs-3">
    <img class="zdjecie" src="zdjecie.jpg" title="zdjecie.jpg"/>
    <div id="kontakt">
     <p>
      <span class="kontakt">KONTAKT</span><br />
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></i><br />
      (+48) 799-981-252<br />
      <a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">mmsmsy@gmail.com</a><br />
     <br />
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i><br />
      <a href="http://www.mmsmsy.com" target="_blank">mmsmsy.com</a>
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <script src="scrollAnim.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Now if I wanted to animate the bar back to width: "0" when it's not in viewport it's not responding. I just noticed it's going back to 0 width after a couple of seconds of delay (why, I have no idea) and then won't slide out right any more until the next refresh of website. The new code to reverse is:

    if (!isElementInViewport($elem)) {
  jQuery('.skillbar').each(function(){
   jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
    width: "0"
   },1000);
  });
 }

Comment: the div remains in an animated state after it comes into view, attempts to reset the width to zero are immediately replaced by the animation. Thus I've  edited the answer to add an 'else' condition and applied jquery `stop` animation to all of the bars before zeroing the widths.

Comment: Much appreciated. Great stuff. I'll keep that in mind for the future.